# Toyota Hilux 2KD-FTV and Fortuner 1KD-FTV Vn Turbo Problem (P1264)

Tags: toyota, turbocharger, hilux

I have been dealing with this problem on Toyota hilux for almost 5 months and last week I encountered Toyota Fortuner with exactly the same problem. They both throw DTC P1264 - VN Turbo Malfunction leading to loss of power

I checked all the wirings are okay, even tried to replace VN Turbo Drivers but no luck. I have been researching on this problem for months now, can anyone help me how to solve this?

Engine on hilux is 2.5L 2KD-FTV, 2009(Model year)

Engine on fortuner is 1KD-FTV

Comment: What engine and year?

Comment: @SolarMike 2009 2kd-ftv

Comment: So 3L or 2.5L? possible differences...

Comment: @SolarMike 2.5L sir